# What's the default install prefix on a linux distro?

Tags: linux, redhat

Software packages with a configure script can specify this manually by adding --prefix:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

My question is, how do I find out what the system's default prefix is?  Is there some command, even on just Redhat that will get you the default install prefix if none is specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It always is `/usr/local/` per autotools defaults. Try running `configure` without a `--prefix` argument; you should get the same result.

And it is a good default as you never want local software to interfere with system software in `/usr` -- which the package managers install.

You could look at the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) documents for a more extended discussion of what goes where.

Comment: You're not replying to the question being asked. The fact that he mentioned `./configure` doesn't mean that the final question he made is related to autotools.

Comment: It's not always entirely true. If you tried installing the zlib for example with autotools predicting location to be /usr/local, then a Ubuntu system can stop from booting altogether, as the desired location seems to be /usr for zlib headers and implementation libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The default install prefix is set by the configure script (via autotools), not "the system".